# Equation $f(f(x))=x$ with $f(2|x-2|+3|x-3|-4)=2|f(x)-2|+3|f(x)-3|-4$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

> If $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ such that
>
> $$f(2|x-2|+3|x-3|-4)=2|f(x)-2|+3|f(x)-3|-4$$
>
> prove that the equation $f(f(x))=x$ has at least one real solution.

---

I don't really know how to proceed for this problem. I was just thinking that if I define

$$g(x)=2|x-2|+3|x-3|-4$$

then I can write the given property as $f(g(x))=g(f(x))$, but how to relate this with $f(f(x))=x$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The equation $g(x)= x$ has two solution i.e. $x\in \{{3\over 2}, {17\over 4}\}$. Then if $a\in \{{3\over 2}, {17\over 4}\}$ we have $$g(f(a))=f(g(a)) =f(a)$$ so $f(a)$ is also fixed point for $g$ so $f(a)\in \{{3\over 2}, {17\over 4}\}$. Also $f(b)$ is fixed point for $g$ if $b\in \{{3\over 2}, {17\over 4}\}$ and $b\ne a$.

- Case $1$. If $f(a) = a$ or $f(b)=b$ then $f(f(a))=a$ or $f(f(b))=b$ and we are done.
- Case $2$. If $f(a)=b$ and $f(b)= a$ then again  $$f(f(a))=a$$

Comment: Can't we also have $f(a)=f(b)=a$ or $f(a)=f(b)=b$? This is trivial however.

Comment: Yeah, that is considered at case 1

Comment: Yes, sorry, I read it wrongly.